# Is this excerpt from an AI-generated answer re Portugal in WWII based on any real events?

Tags: world-war-two, portugal, diplomatic-history

In [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/72259/was-there-a-german-embassy-open-in-1941-lisbon) re. Lisbon in WWII, an AI-generated answer (now deleted) contained the following text:

> One of the notable aspects of the German embassy in Lisbon was its involvement in the so-called "Lisbon Diplomatic Conferences." These conferences were held in an attempt to establish a peaceful resolution to the ongoing war, and they involved representatives from various countries, including Germany, the United Kingdom, and the United States. While these efforts ultimately did not lead to a resolution, they showcased the diplomatic importance of Lisbon during the war.

My confidence in AI-generated texts is quite low, and googling for "Lisbon diplomatic conferences did not turn up anything useful. I know that WWII was not something that could have been ended on a negotiation table, certainly not from the British POV. And that a high-level negotiation attempt by one part of the German leadership ended in total and dismal failure (the Rudolf Hess flight in 1941).

On the other hand I do not really feel confident enough to just totally dismiss this either, e.g. there might have been tentative, but notable, contacts on a certain range of topics. Any ideas if the quoted text is related to any actual events?

Comment: Seems to me that AI is a distraction here.  If I read this correctly, you're asking whether a Lisbon Diplomatic Conference(s) occurred, and if it had the potential to affect the inception of WWI.    Doesn't make any difference whether the fictitious conference(s) were the fabulation of AI, or of someone with a political agenda.  What matters is whether they can be reconciled with the historical record/narrative.

Comment: I can easily imagine various embassy folks sitting around drinking port and smoking cigars as they speculated on how the war might end. As an officially sanctioned 'diplomatic conference' - not so much.

Comment: @MCW - I don't know... If it was written by a credible source that's different. However, questions along the lines of "I heard a rando in a bar say that..." often aren't well-received here, on the theory that there's an infinite amount of BS people can make up, and only a limited amount of us. AI-generated text one could argue is of that ilk.

Comment: OTOH, we aren't exactly drowning in great questions right now, so we can probably afford the time to address this one. :-)

Comment: As a minor conference (much smaller than the one made up by the AI), the 28th of June of 1940 Portugal and Spain signed in Lisbon a (provisional) Treaty of Friendship and No-Agression between the two countries. The Treaty tried to keep the Iberian Peninsula out of the war, by not allowing the UK to invade Spain through Portugal (with whom the British colllaborated) or Germany to invade also Spain in response to a real or suspected British invasion.

Comment: @CarlosMartin - It looks like you might be talking about the [Iberian Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberian_Pact), but Germany and the UK were not parties to it, and the USA was not in the war at the time, and did not attend.

Comment: @T.E.D That's why I said "between Spain and Portugal".

Comment: See my answer to: [Was there a German embassy open in 1941 Lisbon?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/72287/38607) which contains a link to a PDF about *Allied Relations and Negotiations With Portugal - U.S. Department of State*. No meantion of a 'Lisbon Diplomatic Conferences', but does summarizes the negotiations that took place.

Comment: @T.E.D.  I don't disagree.  But "AI" is not the issue.  The title places AI first, but I think the actual questions are (in rough order of priority) Did the Lisbon Conference occur? Did the Lisbon Conference affect WWII? The credibility of the source is a tool to answer those questions, and AI is merely an armature to help understand the credibility of the source.   The distinction isn't important; not worth more than a comment...but I think I typed that before there was an answer, and I thought that a revision might add focus and improve the chance that someone would answer.

Comment: At least to my eye the goal is to attract help from someone who has an interest in WWII diplomatic history.   The current title might be more effective in attracting the attention of AI historians....  Again, there is nothing wrong with the question - I was just trying to suggest an edit that would be more likely to attract more helpful research.

Comment: @MCW I have to agree and was tempted to edit the title to reflect the real question instead of mentioning AI (as someone coming from the HNQ without any context of the real question)

Comment: [Googling "Lisbon Diplomatic Conferences"](https://www.google.com/search?q="Lisbon+Diplomatic+Conferences") turns up this question and one other link that does not seem to work.  So it seems there were no *so-called "Lisbon Diplomatic Conferences"*, though there have been diplomatic meetings in Lisbon including [various treaties of Lisbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Lisbon_(disambiguation)) and [Lisbon agreements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisbon_Agreement)

Comment: AI is relevant because AI hallucinations look very different from human lies. They tend to be written in a serious style, serving no particular agenda, giving them a veneer of plausibility. But because ChatGPT has these hallucinations all the time, it's barely worth trying to disprove them - if there's no Wikipedia article about these conferences, there's no reason to think they exist.

Comment: Sorry, but basing a question on AI-generated answer is ridiculous. ChatGPT and its analogs generate texts based on patterns found in existing sources. Sometimes it leads to real facts incorporated in the answers. Other times, AI generates plausibly sounding texts. Asking whether the AI answer is true because it sounds plausible is completely missing the point that plausibility is a target function of the generator. You can ask ChatGPT "Who was the commander of 23d Portuguese tank brigade during WW2" and it will give a plausibly sounding name, but is there a point trying to confirm this?

Answer (score 14):

Turns out the [US government keeps records on all the international conferences](https://www.archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/043.html) it attends, and there is no record of it attending any such conference in Lisbon.

Before the war, the last conference in Lisbon attended by the USA was this one in 1934:

> 43.11.15 Records relating to the third meeting of the International Technical Consulting Committee on Radio Communications (ITCCRC)
>
> History: ITTCCRC established as a result of the International
> Radiotelegraph Conference held in Washington, 1927 (SEE 43.2.15), and
> reestablished by the International Radio and Telegraph Conferences
> held in Madrid, 1932 (SEE 43.2.25), to study and provide opinions on
> technical radio questions submitted to it by government regulatory
> bodies and radio operating companies. Third meeting held in Lisbon,
> September 22-October 10, 1934, to review opinions.

The next one wasn't until the 1950's:

> 43.7.14 Records relating to meetings of the foreign ministers of France, the United Kingdom, the United States, and the Federal
> Republic of Germany
>
> History: Foreign ministers of the United States, the United Kingdom,
> and France met in London, February 17-19, 1952. In addition to meeting
> among themselves, the three foreign ministers met, February 18-19,
> 1952, with the foreign minister of the Federal Republic of Germany.
>
> Textual Records: Records relating to discussions of the status of
> Germany at the foreign ministers' meetings in London, February 13-19,
> 1952, and Lisbon, February 20-26, 1952. Records of North Atlantic
> Treaty Council preparations, Lisbon, February 1952.

Its possible there was a conference the USA didn't attend of course, but since the AI specifically said it did, its statement appears to be wrong.

Comment: Kind of an appalling thing to be wrong about and post on a History site too...

Comment: This is ***at least the third instance*** I have noticed that AI generated answers created fictitious sources or events.  The danger is that they look good enough to draw careless votes which means 'fake history' (lies) will soon be established and accepted as fact by less discerning readers/voters.

Comment: @justCal - Gaming the reputation system is one thing, and I can even live with posts being wrong, but posting flat out made up sh*t is quite another.

Comment: The poster likely doesn't even know its fake (the conference mentioned). This answer was just straight copy/pasted from AI output, with no attempt to disguise the content.

Comment: @justCal - You're right, but that's not a good excuse. It merely drops the crime down to reckless endangerment.

Comment: Isn't this one of the reasons why Chatbot-generated content is banned?

Comment: @Barmar - It [was banned here on History](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4407/771) (arguably) on the [FuzzyChef Principle](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9992/11380): posting a question here rather than asking Chatbot directly is an implicit request to get an answer from a *human*, not the AI. I can't speak for other SE network site policies. I believe its banned network wide as a violation of the network's [authentic use policy](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage), which is a somewhat similar stance.

Comment: @justCal, it's even worse than you think. Youtube has been swarmed with "science" and "history" channels now that are entirely AI generated videos.